# Removing Website Form in Wordpress Custom

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms

I have built a custom theme using wordpress and I'm trying to remove the "Website Field" in the Comments form.

I have tried inserting this code in my function.php but it does not seem to work.

```
//REMOVE WEBSIE FORM IN COMMENTS
function remove_comment_fields($fields) {
    unset($fields['url']);
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','remove_comment_fields');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem with the help of this site.

http://gerardmcgarry.com/blog/wordpress-how-remove-website-url-field-comment-form

Apparently i was missing the comments.php included in the theme. So what i did is I copied the comments.php located in wp-includes/theme-compat then paste it in my own custom theme.

Then i erase/remove this.

```
<p><input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo  esc_attr($comment_author_url); ?>" size="22" tabindex="3" />
<label for="url"><small><?php _e('Website'); ?></small></label></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pu t his one in your theme's  functions.php file and it should work

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'url_filtered');
function url_filtered($fields)
{
  if(isset($fields['url']))
   unset($fields['url']);
  return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Still the same. I'm testing the wordpress website on a localhost(XAMPP). I have been googling my problem and all the results give the exact same answer and have been working for everyone else. Yet when try inserting the code in the function.php it does not seem to work

Comment: Nevermind i managed to fix my problem. Just have to google deeper :)